# How do I make vertices more visible

Tags: mesh

I'm using Blender 2.79. I think I've seen people have their vertices in edit mode colored bright yellow and in larger scale than normal. But I can't find any settings for this. Does anybody know where this setting is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender 2.79 : you will find these options in User Preferences:

**File** > **User Preferences** > **Themes** > **3D View** >  vertex colors and vertex size :

[image]

[image]